# What aspects of Java development do IDE's hide but developers should know?

Tags: java

I am primarily a C# developer, and I am writing a project in Java to try and learn the language (and so I can point to concrete examples of code I have written in Java, to help employability).

I was wondering what aspects of the Java development workflow that I should know about that are traditionally hidden (or taken care of) by the IDE.

For example, I know I need to figure out how libraries are referenced in Java.  In C# libraries are referenced in the standard `.csproj` file, but at first glance it seems like each IDE has their own method of referencing projects, and I should probably learn how Java finds .jar packages during execution.

Another thing I know I need to figure out is exactly how Java determines the program entry point (since swing components seem to have a `public static main` function as well).

What are other things that I should know about the Java "compilation" and execution processes that the IDE seems to hide?

Comment: Google java_home, java class path, Javac et-all for starters.

Comment: `.csproj` is a Visual Studio file. To the best of my knowledge neither `csc` nor the .NET runtime will use it to resolve library references.

Comment: You should probably split your question into three: "how are library references handled in Java when compiling with javac and running applications?", "how does java handle entry points?", and "the rest". Odds are the first two are already answered, the last one is a bad SO question and probably the part that's getting you close votes.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to learn about JAR files and the [Java Manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html), which allows you to do things like specify the main entry point.

The IDE also tries to abstract away a lot of the normal build process, so you will probably want to become at least familiar with [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), which are build tools similar to Make or MSBuild.

And depending on how far down the non-IDE path you need to go, you will want to learn the command line tools that come with the Java SDK:

General tools page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/

Specific important ones:

- [Basic Java commands](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/#basic)
- [Command line security tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/#security)
- [Troubleshooting tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/#troubleshoot) - `jstack`, `jhat`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best place to start would be to read the documentation for the java command line tools.  Look under "Basic Tools" here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/  `java`, `javac`, and `jar` are probably the main ones you'll care about.

Regarding library references, you'll want to understand about the Java classpath, and jar files, and class loaders.  For the entry point, you'll notice that running from the command line requires you to specify which class is going to be checked for a main method.

Answer (score 1):

The libraries are linked by setting the classpath when calling java.exe to run your program. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html) webpage will give you more information on the classpath. Note that various IDE will store the classpath information in a different way, depening on their method to store the project information. This is independant from the Java language itself.

You can specify your program entry point when building your jar file (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)). When you double-click on a jar, this is the `main` method that will be called. Otherwise, you can specify which class you want to call when calling the java.exe program. See the java.exe help by calling 
`java -help` on the command line.